# Constraints with multiple subviews

Tags: objective-c, user-interface, constraints

My app consists of a deck of cards. Each card itself is created in a class called draggableview. Draggableview has a scrollview, so that the user can scroll through a bunch of images relevant to the card. On the first view, there are buttons, which I created in draggableview.xib and have their methods in the draggableview class. However, as you scroll past the first view, all the other views do not have these buttons.

EDIT: 
I've partially solved my problem. In initwithView, I added each button as a subview of draggableview. Now, the buttons appear in all the views of scrollview. In storyboard, I deleted and added new constraints. And in storyboard, the buttons move accordingly. However, in simulator, they're stuck in the right hand corner of the screen.

For this first try, I did this first with one button (review button).

my initWithFrame method:

```
 - (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        [self addSubviewFromNib];
        [self setupView];
        panGestureRecognizer = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer     alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(beingDragged:)];
        cardWidth = frame.size.width;
        cardHeight = frame.size.height;
        type = 0;
        panGestureRecognizer.delegate = self;
        panGestureRecognizer.cancelsTouchesInView = NO;
        _backgroundScrollView.panGestureRecognizer.cancelsTouchesInView = NO;

        likeBadge.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"likeBadge"];
        likeBadge.alpha = 0;
        likeBadge.layer.zPosition=99;
        passBadge.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"passBadge"];
        passBadge.alpha = 0;
        passBadge.layer.zPosition=99;
        self.backgroundScrollView.contentSize = self.bounds.size;
        [self addSubview: reviewButton];
        [self addGestureRecognizer:panGestureRecognizer];
    }
    return self;
}
```

How it looks in simulator: [image]

Comment: Which are the buttons?   `likeBadge` and `passBadge`?  And are they children of the draggable view, not the scroll view?  This would change my answer dramatically.

Comment: No -- the buttons i'm talking about are, I assume, uploaded from addSubViewFromNib (see my earlier comment below about my mistake). They are specifically: phone, map, menu, review, and share buttons. And yes, they're children of draggableview (the nib file), not the scroll view.

Comment: Have you set the color of primary content view to clear?  That's different from setting it's alpha to zero.

Comment: like badge and pass badge aren't actually in primary content view (in case that affects your suggestions) -- and setting primary content view's color to clear didn't do anything - still couldn't scroll since making pcv a sibling rather than child of background scroll view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to adding each button as a subview of draggableView in initWithFrame, I also added each button's constraints programmatically. For some reason, this allowed me to move the buttons around (whereas nothing in storyboard was successful) and now they're on all the views of scrollview.